# Progress bars using broadcast notation in Julia?

Tags: loops, syntax, julia, progress-bar

In Julia, some amazing packages like `ProgressMeter` provide an easy API for displaying progress bars in the REPL. However, it seems like they only work with regular for loops, comprehensions and map/reduce. So, e.g., these work:

```
using ProgressMeter

function sleepyAdd(arg::Int64)
    sleep(1)
    return arg + 1000
end

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Progress bar with for loop
@showprogress for num in nums
    sleepyAdd(num)
end

# Progress bar with comprehension
@showprogress [sleepyAdd(num) for num in nums]
```

Howeve, you can't just use that with broadcast notation (so `@showprogress sleepyAdd.(nums)` doesn't work), which is a shame because brodcasting functions is one of the best features of Julia's syntax: elegant, simple and concise.

**Is there any way around this limitation?**

Answer (score 3):

The convenient macro `@showprogress` doesn't work in this case. But doing `@macroexpand @showprogress...` gives what is needed to get a working version for specific uses (and maybe for someone to update ProgressMeter.jl):

```
let t_nums = nums, 
    t_meter = ProgressMeter.Progress(ProgressMeter.length(t_nums)),
    t_wrapper = ProgressMeter.ProgressWrapper(t_nums, t_meter)
    # now comes the comprehension
    [sleepyAdd(num) for num in t_wrapper]
end
```

And you get the same effect as the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @Dan! However, I couldn't quite follow your code (I'm new to Julia and don't know anything about @macroexpand or metaprogramming...). Could you post a MWE? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, okay, just take the last line off the code in the question and copy-paste code in this answer and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is - here's a link to the only mention of broadcasting in ProgressMeter's issues:

https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl/issues/31#issuecomment-448558683

in which Tim says (in 2018) that he's not aware of anyone working on it.